# Sorting Excel data (excluding specific entries)

Tags: excel, sorting

I'm having trouble sorting data in my Excel file. I want to sort the data first by Date & Time and then by STORE. However, I want to exclude the entries with WAREHOUSE and OFFICE. It's a bit difficult to explain what I'm trying to achieve, so I've prepared an example to illustrate the desired sorting.

[Screen with before sorting and sorted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Rq3.png)

Here's what I want to achieve:

The first row should be for STORE 1 because it has the latest Date & Time entry.
The second row should also be for STORE 1, even though its Date & Time entry is slightly later. This is because STORE 1 had the latest date, and all subsequent rows with STORE 1 in the FROM/TO column should be listed here.
The third row should be for STORE 2 because there are no more results from STORE 1, and the second latest entry was for STORE 2.
And so on...

Could someone please guide me on how to achieve this type of sorting in Excel? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Data:

| Date & Time | FROM | TO | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12.05.2023 05:00 | WAREHOUSE | OFFICE 1 | 500 |
| 12.05.2023 06:00 | WAREHOUSE | OFFICE 2 | 300 |
| 12.05.2023 07:00 | WAREHOUSE | OFFICE 3 | 200 |
| 12.05.2023 08:00 | OFFICE 1 | OFFICE 4 | 450 |
| 12.05.2023 09:00 | OFFICE 4 | STORE 1 | 10 |
| 12.05.2023 10:00 | OFFICE 4 | STORE 2 | 10 |
| 12.05.2023 11:00 | OFFICE 4 | STORE 3 | 10 |
| 12.05.2023 12:00 | OFFICE 4 | STORE 4 | 10 |
| 12.05.2023 13:00 | OFFICE 4 | STORE 5 | 10 |
| 12.05.2023 14:00 | OFFICE 4 | STORE 6 | 10 |
| 12.05.2023 15:00 | OFFICE 4 | STORE 7 | 10 |
| 12.05.2023 16:00 | STORE 5 | OFFICE 4 | 1 |
| 12.05.2023 17:00 | STORE 1 | OFFICE 4 | 1 |
| 12.05.2023 18:00 | STORE 3 | OFFICE 4 | 1 |
| 12.05.2023 19:00 | OFFICE 4 | STORE 2 | 5 |
| 12.05.2023 20:00 | OFFICE 4 | STORE 8 | 5 |

Comment: You are including `OFFICE` in the output, but you mentioned you want to exclude them. Please put your input data in [table markdown format](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#). Just copy it from excel, generate it and copy back to your question leaving a blank line. It helps to reproduce your sample without entering the data manually in Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the table format suggestion - done. Regarding excluding OFFICE and WAREHOUSE, I don't want separate rows or sorting for them. The first result pertains to STORE 1, even if FROM/TO was OFFICE, it still appears due to STORE. The first 4 rows represent WAREHOUSE - OFFICE, which I skipped during sorting (because there wasn't STORE). The sorted data on the screen should provide a better understanding.

Comment: thanks for the update. I would suggest to spend sometime trying to explain the rules associated with the sorting. Do you have really a first sorting criteria? How date should be sorted, ascending or descending?, When to use the second sorting criteria, etc. How to interpret exclusion criteria?, provide enough samples to understand all possible scenarios. Comments are for just minor clarifications, your question really needs more clarity. The sample output is not for guessing the rules, it should be for illustrative purpose of the rules you have provided. Thanks